# Timekeeper MySQL-Structure

Tags: mysql, timer

I'm trying to make a timekeeper and thinking about a good database structure.

The idea is the following:
On a frontend (e.g. Website, a Java-Application, what ever) you can create a timer with a specific name.
To keep the timekeeper running even if you close the frontend I thought of having a table, which keeps the starttime (as datetime).
And if you stop the timer the difference between starttime and the endtime would be the total spent time.
So far so good.

But I also want to add the possibility to continue a timer.
So I thought about having two tables.
One to keep the total time (with the columns "name" and "timeSpent") and one to keep each single "start-stop"-action.
So if you create a new timer it creates a new row in the first table with the name and a new row in the second table with the starttime.
If you then stop the timer, the time difference gets calculated and the first table will be updated (timespent = difference) (by using a procedure).
So that if you restart/continue the timer it should create again a new row in the second table and by stopping, again update the first table (timespent = timespent + difference).

Now the question is:
Is this a good way, do I've missed something, or does someone have a better idea for this?

Comment: pick a programming language, throw out some code.

Comment: the programming language shouldn't matter. it's just about the database structure. so it's (My)SQL.

Comment: I thought it was a complicated question, sorry, seem like high level concepts, kicking around tires, and the such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved it this way...
First, the Table

```
CREATE TABLE Efforts
(
  ID                  INT UNSIGNED        NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  User                INT UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
  Project             INT UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
  Task                INT UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
  Note                TEXT                NOT NULL,

  Date                DATETIME            NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  TimerStart          DATETIME,
  TimerEnd            DATETIME,
  TimeSpent           DECIMAL(10,2)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',

  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (User)
    REFERENCES Users(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Project)
    REFERENCES Projects(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Task)
    REFERENCES Tasks(ID)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB, CHARSET = utf8, COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

And now the trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_timespent BEFORE UPDATE ON Efforts
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE duration DECIMAL(10,2);

    IF (NEW.TimerStart IS NOT NULL AND OLD.TimerEnd <> NEW.TimerEnd) THEN
      SELECT CAST((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.TimerStart, NEW.TimerEnd) / 3600) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        INTO duration;

      SET NEW.TimeSpent = (OLD.TimeSpent + duration);
      SET NEW.TimerStart = NULL;
      SET NEW.TimerEnd = NULL;
    END IF;

  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first table should not have a timeSpent column as this could get out of sync with the actual time in the 2nd table (think about race conditions where multiple start/stops happen and the table gets over-ridden).

I do like your idea about having a parent table and a child table. I would suggest the following:

## Timers table

- ID
- Name

## Durations table

- ID
- Timer_id (foreign key of timers)
- start_time
- end_time

Your total time would be the calculation of each end_time - start_time. Something like this would work well:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(time_milis / 1000)
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) as time_milis
   FROM table
)
```

So summary, don't save any calculated values in the rows - it's not a good practice and can lead to the tables being out of sync especially during race conditions. Utilize good foreign key relationships and normalize it.

With two tables like this, you are able to grab all the information you need to regenerate the history if someone closes and re-opens the timer. I think this schema should serve you well.

Comment: Agreed, didn't thought about race conditions.
But what if I want to edit the total time?
Let's say I forgot to stop a timer, so it tracked time while it shouldn't.
First thing in my mind is > okay, then just adjust the specific row in durations. But what I want is that the user only sees the total time and can edit it.  
I thought about this:
if the user edits the total time, it creates again a new row in durations but with the end time earlier than the start time (so old total time - new total time). so the actual time should be a negative value. is that possible?

Comment: By only keeping track of the start_time and the stop_time, you take duration out of the equation and allow the user to be able to start the timer, close the app and then log back in and still have the timer going. If you require duration to be a field, the user would not be able to have the timer running in the background. A null value for end_time is good enough to specify that the timer has not stopped and should continue, and update that when the timer is complete. I don't know your use case, but most timers do not allow you to adjust durations.

Comment: The use case is a project timekeeper like Harvest. In Harvest you can start/stop a timer and also edit the total time.
Maybe race conditions aren't really a problem, because each timer belongs to just one specific user